# Number of way of wearing 5 rings in 5 fingers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many numbers of ways are there to arrange 5 distinct rings in 5 fingers with a restriction that not more than 3 rings can be put on any finger?

---

I solved this as follows:

#### Case I (2 fingers)

$\binom{5}{2} \cdot 2\cdot \binom{5}{3} \cdot 3!\cdot 2!= 2400$

#### Case II (3 fingers)

##### for the case (3,1,1)

$\binom{5}{3} \cdot 3\cdot \binom{5}{3}\cdot 3!\cdot 2!= 3600$

##### for the case (2,2,1)

$\binom{5}{3} \cdot 3\cdot \binom{5}{2}\cdot 2!\cdot \binom{3}{2} \cdot 2!= 
3600$

#### Case III (4 fingers)

$\binom{5}{4} \cdot 4\cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot 2!\cdot 3!= 2400$

#### Case IV (5 fingers)

$\binom{5}{5} \cdot5!= 120$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of possible arrangements of rings on a hand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792429/number-of-possible-arrangements-of-rings-on-a-hand)

Comment: @lulu that appears to be a totally different question (the number of rings is different and there are no restrictions).

Comment: @EspeciallyLime  Totally different?  The duplicate covers $n$ rings and $m$ fingers...this problem is a special case.  True, the duplicate allows for some rings to be left off, but the solutions all address the case where a specified number of rings are worn.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime  True, the cap of $3$ per finger means that  you need Stars and Bars with caps...I agree that's not covered by the duplicate, though for such small numbers, it's not much of a problem.  Still, I'll withdraw the close vote.

Comment: @lulu: I think you need to add all Arsalan's results.

Comment: @Dominique  Ah, thank you.  That wasn't clear to me (still waking up).  I'll delete my comment, and this one soon.

Comment: @lulu: waking up? At 3 o'clock in the afternoon? Something tells me you're living at the west side of the Atlantic :-)

Comment: @Dominique  Fraid so...

Answer (score 4):

I agree with your result.

Another way to see it:  Use the Stars and Bars methodology as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792429/number-of-possible-arrangements-of-rings-on-a-hand) to solve the unrestricted problem (so we allow a finger to have four or five rings).  We get $$\binom 94\times 5!=126\times 5!$$

Now we have to remove the bad patterns.

There are $5!$ ways to put all the rings on a single finger, and there are $5$ fingers so there are $5\times 5!$ bad patterns of this type.

For the case where one ring has $4$ and another has $1$, pick the $4-$finger and the $1-$finger ($20$ ways to choose them).  Then there are $5!$ ways to put $4$ of the rings on the $4-$finger ($5$ choices for the lowest, $4$ for the next, $3$ for the next, and $2$ for the top),  and each choice determines what goes on the $1-$finger.  Thus there are $20\times 5!$ bad patterns of this type.

Thus there are $25\times 5!$ bad patterns in toal making the final result $$(126-25)\times 5!=101\times 5!=12120$$

Which, I believe, matches your total.